# Execution time of reducer in mapred

Tags: mapreduce

Hi I am using mapreduce framework for calculating the information values for attributes in a table.Its working fine with 2 lac records ie: getting correct IV values but when m trying to run it for 80 lacs of record its taking too long around 10 hours or even more.I have increased the number of reduced task to 200 and have also introduced a combiner class but still the problem remains the same....i guess its not a logical error but some architectural or configuration issue which i am not able to trace.....please provide the suggestions asap

Comment: How long will it take for the Mapper part of the job to get completed?And what is the number of configured reduce task slots in your cluster?

Comment: Mapper takes 3 mins for its completion and number of reduced task slot is 100

Comment: Can you check what is the actual number of reduce task running for you job.I think it may be less than 100.

Comment: no i already checked it thrice...also i have tried to increase it to 300 but getting the same issue .... i guess its a problem of perfect balance or something like that but i really don't know how to sort it out